# Access ng-repeat value in Jade

Tags: angularjs, pug

New to Node, Angular, and Jade -- Looking to access an Angular repeat value VIA Jade.

The current code

```
tr(
    ng-repeat="item in $data"
)
td(...)
    span {{item.stuff}}
```

This successfully creates a table of `item.stuff`. I'm looking to use Jade's conditional statements on `item`. Such as: `case #{ item.stuff }`, but item is undefined in this scenario.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve? have you looked at http://jade-lang.com/reference/iteration/ ?

Comment: I have looked into that, and it works to an extent, but it makes things a bit more challenging as far as being able to access the elements in the rows. I'm trying to access `item` in Jade without using angular syntax. Since the variable is local to Angular, is that possible?

Comment: Short answer is you cant... you can use Angular filters and directives to achieve what you need. Jade handles variables sent from the server - Angular hangs on the client

Comment: @tymeJV Hmm. This is a lot more complicated than anticipated. I suspect I can't a Jade variable to Angular either, correct?

Comment: @user2402831 -- You can.. you can use `ng-init` and write the value from Jade in on page load. Ex: `ng-init="('#{jadeVariable}')")`